# PHP unable to read object from json encode

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am sending a request to youtube API to get a playlist:

```
      // make GET request to the YouTube API
      $response = wp_remote_request( 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId='.$playlist_id.'&key='.$api_key.'&order=date&maxResults=25',
      array(
          'method'     => 'GET'
        )
      );
```

After getting it I would like to have it in JSON so I am using:

```
      $json = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
      $json_encoded = json_encode($json, true);
```

If I am right this now should be a JSON representation of the supplied value. So I am getting:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXevLePAydmU/Q2DmelXR9Ne48evrmJE9Q4yVvpU\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CAoQAE",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 36,
        "resultsPerPage": 25
    },
    "items": [ ...
```

And I would like to store only the items. One would think that I can now access them via:

```
$json_encoded['items'];
```

And then store it into WordPress db like this:

```
      // if we have any items update the db with those results
      if ( isset ( $json_encoded['items'] )) {
        $videos['json'] = $json_encoded['items'];
        update_option( 'wpc_ylp_videos', $videos );
      }
```

Well, unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'items' in /Users/tobias/Sites/videos.dev.cc/wp-content/plugins/videos/includes/videos.php on line 61
"
```

AND

```
Notice: Undefined index: json in /Users/tobias/Sites/videos.dev.cc/wp-content/plugins/videos/includes/videos.php on line 67
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong but can not wrap my head around this. How can I access the items object? Is my usage of json_encode right?

Comment: `json_encode` converts to a string. I believe you are looking for `json_decode` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Ty Bailey, thanks, that was exactly the issue! Oh my.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you that don't read comments; The answer is to use `json_decode()` instead of `json_encode()`.

`json_encode()` converts to a string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php